# Find distinct from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 columns called price and PID in database called `seatinginfo`.
Both columns will have multiple of the same values like

```
pid 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3
price 10,10,30,40,60,80,70,90,90,90,90 etc
```

I'm looking to make a query that will give me a list of all unique prices and pick just 1 or the max connected pid.
So example I only want one price,pid like 10,1 30,1 40,1 60,2 etc

Thanks

Comment: I can do select price,PID from seatinginfo group by price,PID but it won’t give me unique price. Will only give me where price and PID combined are unique. I want unique price and idc which PID it gives me as long as it matches any of the price

Comment: rows are not columns, probably you are asking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Ya my bad. I am looking for a list of rows where just price is unique and it can return any of the matching PID.

Comment: You haven't shown anything where there's any sort of relationship between `PID` and `PRICE`. Highly suggest posting a minimally reproduceable sample.

Comment: Are you really still using sql 2008? It has been unsupported for several years now. Time to upgrade to something modern.

Comment: A lot of legacy code and running on many servers. Too much of a headache to upgrade

Comment: Sql server is backwards compatible. Any code that is running today will continue to work in the new version. But that is up to you. It is like you are still running win98 because upgrading is too much hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably as simple as basic aggregation. Something like this should work based on the pretty vague details.

```
select price
    , max(pid)
from YourTable
group by price
```

Comment: Kudos...  I could not figure out what OP was looking for.  +1